# Widget name as variable in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to invoke some Widgets, many Widgets, with names as S1, S2, S3, and so on.  Is it possible to use any variable to do this?  Something like:

```
builder: (context) => S'$i'(),     // with i variable as a counter, for example
```

instead of

```
builder: (context) => S1(),
builder: (context) => S2(),
builder: (context) => S3(),
```

I appreciate your help.  Regards

Comment: If you are needing to do this, it is probably a good sign that you should use some sort of abstraction or inheritance in your classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. I would suggest you use Streambuilder to build your dynamic views.

Comment: Ok @Keezy Silencer, I appreciate your help

Comment: @KeezySilencer I need to show a different widget depending on a state varialble- Is streambuilder appropriate for this case?

Comment: @user3808307 That is the way to go.